# getchar() function to count characters in C

Tags: c, getchar

I have a code that counts the number of characters. It uses getchar() and while execution I use (./a.out < test.txt) where test.txt is locally saved text file. Issue is that the counter is showing a value greater than the characters in the file.

When I use the condition,

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
```

instead of

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

in the function where c is an int defined in main, the counter is correct.

```
int main() 
{
    long nc=0; int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        putchar(c);
        ++nc;
    }
    printf("%ld", nc);
}
```

I think that the issue is due to '\n' character. When I use putchar(c) as shown above, let's say that there are 9 characters in my test.txt file. Now, it should print all the characters in the file followed by 9 as output. But, it prints 10 instead. Also, the command prompt shifts to next line after displaying characters which is the reason behind printing 10 as it counts '\n' as a character. But, from where did that '\n' came from?

Comment: What is the contents of the file? What is the expected output? What is the actual output?

Comment: The problem might be that the editor adds a new line at the end of file by default (even VIM !)

Comment: I randomly typed some characters; the exact text is "hsfiefefd" without quotes which makes up 9 characters.

Comment: `getchar()` gets `ANSI` character. It may get `UTF` letter as one up to four different characters.

Comment: That `\n` is in your file. Use another tool such as `wc` or `od` to convince yourself of the fact. Most probably your editor has added it because a text file should normally end with a `\n`.

Comment: I am using gedit (text editor) on Ubuntu.

Comment: Gedit? An ok editor. What are we supposed to do with the fact that you are using it?

Comment: Beware, if you ever try this on Windows: a newline is coded into two chars '\r' and '\n', but normally getchar() will give you just '\n'. And if your editor stores in UTF there might be a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning that takes some bytes.

Comment: @n.m. It is an answer for other users who were asking about the editor I used, not you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wager that you haven't actually verified the size of your file. Double check the size with either

```sh
ls -ls test.txt
```

or

```sh
wc -c test.txt
```

Open your file in a hex editor. I suspect you will find a new-line character (`0x0A`) at the end.

> But, from where did that '\n' came from?

That depends on  how you created or edited the file in the first place.

If you created using

```sh
echo "Test file" > test.txt
```

for example, then `bash` will automatically add a new-line character at the end. Certain text editors may do the same.

Comment: I opened it using a hex editor. It's output has 0A at the end, but in characters, it shows a "." in the end. Does that represent newline?

Comment: @Kuljeet: Yes. The `hexedit` program - and probably other hexadecimal editors - use `.` for characters they can not print (e.g. control characters such as new-line, line-feed, etc.).